# How can I add a new token to a given tokenizer and train it ONLY on a specific task?

Tags: tokenize, large-language-model, huggingface

I want to add a new special token to a given model's tokenizer and optimize it ONLY on a specific downstream task.

This is my code so far:

```
new_token = "[SPECIAL]"
num_added_tokens = tokenizer.add_tokens([new_token])
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
# Unfreeze new token embeddings
model.gpt_neox.embed_in.weight[-num_added_tokens:].requires_grad
prefix = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(model.gpt_neox.embed_in.weight[-num_added_tokens:], freeze=False) #create learnble tokens
optimizer = optim.AdamW(prefix.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
```

I add the special token to each of the input texts in the batch, gets the loss

```
 loss = model(**tokenized_inputs, labels=padded_labels)["loss"]
```

back propagates - the gradient is calculated but the step doesn't change the embedding of the newly added token.

can someone help me with that?